# Formatting issue in "{{start_time | date:'HH:mm'}}" - getting warning and formatting not working

Tags: angularjs

Getting below warning and I don't see the format being displayed in input.

> The specified value "{{start_time | date:'HH:mm'}}" does not conform
>   to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or
>   "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is
>   000-999.

```
<input type="time" value="{{start_time | date:'HH:mm'}}">
```

Current output
[image]

Expected hh:mm

Comment: What is start_time?

Comment: Most likely start_time isn't a valid date...

Comment: `start_date !== start_time`

Comment: my mistake its "start_time": "2017-08-29T17:15:16.814Z"

Comment: Why using `value` instead of `ng-model`?

Comment: I don't know how to format in case of ng-model

Comment: You will have warnings due to interpolation, `ngValue` can help you to get rid of this warnings, but you'll probably want to retrive this value somehow in your controller. In case of `ng-model` you just need to pass `Date` object instead of a string. I can try to add a code snippet if you still need it.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash `<input class="form-control text-uppercase" type="time" ng-model="start_time">` How should I format time as hh:mm while still using ngModel

Comment: @ShantanuGupta try something [like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/5XGrCfcpXFCHzP6GTPzo?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have your date in `start_date` and are trying to use `start_time` on the front-end. This should work:

```
<input type="time" ng-value="start_date | date : 'HH:mm'">
```

Example: [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SOU988PdtSZjY1INwvbn?p=preview)

---

**UPDATE:** to allow for updating the model, you should add a filter:

```
.filter('parseDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
      if (angular.isDate(date)) return date;
      return new Date(Date.parse(date.replace(/:\d{2}[.,]\d{3}Z$/, '')));
    };
});

var start_time = "2017-08-29T17:15:16.814Z";

$scope.start_date = $filter('parseDate')(start_time);
```

Example: [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qwKpjr677aA52HlYvcbT?p=preview)

Comment: I could see your sample code working with warning in console. Same thing is happening with me i.e. at one place it is showing in formatted way while on other tab it isn't, any clue?

Comment: That's just a warning (not an error), but you can get rid of it by using ng-value instead (updated by answer to reflect that). Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't give two way binding

Comment: Updated to allow for two way data binding :)

Comment: Did the update (with two way data binding) work for you @ShantanuGupta?

Comment: It isn't working for me. I tried binding using the code you provided. however it's not doing two way binding as well as input format is still hh:mm:ss

Comment: Is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qwKpjr677aA52HlYvcbT?p=preview) working for you? It appears to be working for me...

Comment: Yes, I can see plunker working however my code isn't

Comment: Then it appears you have another issue on your hands @ShantanuGupta. You'll have to ask a separate question based on the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).